# RSS feed for twitter's trending topics

Tags: rss, twitter

How can I get RSS Feed of Twitter's Trending Topics of India?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to write a custom [yahoo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) You can get some ideas from these [pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/search?q=twitter+trends&x=0&y=0) related to twitter trends.

Comment: I created one of my own using yahoo pipes...had to do some research but got it working...thanks...

Comment: Link: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=9c08bf0e0f4f18de294e1a8a21c12eb9